# Returning one row per id with inner join

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

In a SQL Server database I have two tables, one a parent of the other. The child table has a many-to-one relationship with the parent. I need to return only one record for each parent with the top most corresponding child table record. However I cannot figure out how to do this.

The following is the query I have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    products.id,
    sku,
    name,
    mediaid
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN 
    productmedia ON products.id = productmedia.productid
WHERE
    sku IN ('HCFL 207 23 (A)','HCFL 207 22 (A)','HCFL 207 21 (A)','HCFL 207 20 (A)')
    AND productmedia.sort = 100
```

And I am getting the following:

```
183816  HCFL 207 20 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 1/4", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN   2929082
183816  HCFL 207 20 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 1/4", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN   2929083
183817  HCFL 207 21 (A) HCFL SERIES-2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 5/16", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT-ASIAN    2929138
183817  HCFL 207 21 (A) HCFL SERIES-2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 5/16", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT-ASIAN    2929139
183818  HCFL 207 22 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 3/8", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN   2929086
183818  HCFL 207 22 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 3/8", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN   2929087
183819  HCFL 207 23 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 7/16", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN  2929084
183819  HCFL 207 23 (A) HCFL SERIES- 2-BOLT FLANGE, ECCENTRIC LOCKING COLLAR, BORE DIA. 1 7/16", WIDE INNER RACE INSERT -ASIAN  2929085
```

Comment: What is the definition of the topmost child and which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: show us table structure of parent and child tables...

Comment: Which database server (and version) do you use? There could be different solutions in different database engines.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: This is a SQL database version 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` is your friend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    products.id,
    sku,
    name,
    mediaid
FROM
    products
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            * -- List the required columns!
        FROM
            productmedia
        WHERE           
            products.id = productmedia.productid
            AND productmedia.sort = 100 
        ORDER BY
            YourOrderColumn -- Change it to your required order!
    ) AS X
WHERE
    sku IN ('HCFL 207 23 (A)','HCFL 207 22 (A)','HCFL 207 21 (A)','HCFL 207 20 (A)')
```

Comment: If you want that column in your output (result), then you should add it to botch selects. If you don't want to display it, you can skip it from both selects. We can not guess which columns comming from which table, because you did not mentioned a table structure and your query is not clear. Just a tip: If you use two or more tables in a query, add them an alias and always include that alias in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as(
select s.id studentId, s.name, c.class, 
ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by class order by s.id) rn 
from Student s
inner join class c on s.classId = c.id
)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

You can change "order by s.id" to any other column which you think is based to order the result.